# what is the complexity of the following code?

Tags: c++

What is the complexity of the following piece of code??

```
for (int i = 1; i * i <= n; i++)
{
   if (n%i == 0)
     //do anything
}
```

Comment: Any guesses yourself? I mean, we're here to help, not to do your work for you.

Comment: It depends upon what "do anything" *does*. I could write an "anything" that creates a O(1) loop, an O(n^.5) loop, or any other complexity.

Comment: -1: If you put as much effort into solving this homework problem as you have in trolling for other people to solve it for you, you'd be done by now.

Comment: @WhozCraig I dont know...if they sleep through class, didnt get the textbook, and google is blocked on campus, SO might be their only hope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop runs √*n* times, and the conditional is met every time `i` is a factor of `n` — the latter is a non-trivial condition and needs to be analysed carefully. It depends on the prime factorisation of `n`. For example, if `n` is prime, the condition is only true once, for `i == 1`, and never again.